# Using GetWindowModuleFileName in JNA

Tags: java, windows, jna

There is my list of processes:

```
public class lab2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Kernel32 kernel32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
        User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();
        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
                Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        char path[] = new char[512];
        HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, path, 512);

        try {
            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {
                System.out.println(Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile)
                        + "\t" + Native.toString(path));
            }
        } finally {
            kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set a variable **path** the full path to the file. I got an error **@Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to WinDef.HWND@** in `HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, path, 512);` Where did I go wrong? How to do it right? Thank you.

Comment: It's my first introduction to the JNA library. I don't understand how to display the path of each process, and I would be grateful for your advice.

Comment: To solve this I'd have to do exactly what you have to now -- check the MSDN entry on GetWindowModuleFileName, and then try to get it to work with my JNA application. Again, there's where I suggest that you start.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I tried to realize it like this: `user32.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, path, 512);
    System.out.println(Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile)
      + "\t" + Native.toString(path));` I got an error: **hWnd cannot be resolved to a variable.** What I forgot?

Comment: You need to edit your original post showing your new code. Of course before you can use the method you must declare it in the interface, and show show us this declaration. Before you can use hWnd, you must declare a variable by this name, show us this declaration. Again, show your best good-faith effort to solve this in your original question along with any and all full error messages and descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the function wrong.

- You're using the hWnd variable on the same line as you declare it.
- And hWnd doesn't yet hold a reference to a viable window.
- And I have no idea why you're trying to put the int returned into an HWND variable. This makes no sense, and is the source of your errors.
- Again for the function to work, your HWND variable, hWnd needs to refer to a viable window handle. You may need to call another JNA function to get this handle.

e.g.,

```
  User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
  char path[] = new char[512];

  long sleepTime = 2000;
  try {
     Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

  HWND hWnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
  user32.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, path, 512);
  System.out.println("Foreground Window Module FileName: " + 
          Native.toString(path));

  user32.GetWindowText(hWnd, path, 512);
  System.out.println("Window text is: " + Native.toString(path));
```